# After adding Python to my windows PATH Powershell stopped recognizing simple commands like cmd and help. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Tags: python, powershell, path, windows-10

I added Python to my Windows path so that I could use the pip and pyinstaller commands, now commands like cmd, py, and even the 'help' command aren't recognized by Powershell. Trying to use these commands results in the "cmd : The term 'cmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program." error. I am an amateur developer and I am still very new to programming and file management, I don't know what caused this but I suspect it may have to do with adding Python to the windows PATH. I've looked all over the internet and tried everything I found, nothing seems to work. As I have already said, I am very new to all of this and I am almost certain that I am omitting at least some relevant information but I don't know what else you might need to help me, so I am happy to provide any additional information as needed.

ex. When trying the 'help' command in Powershell, Powershell seems to recognize it as 'more.com', so it would seem that Powershell recognizes the 'help' alias but doesn't know what it's supposed to do.

```
PS C:\Users\julien> help
more.com : The term 'more.com' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:9 char:19
+ } else { $input | more.com }
+                   ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (more.com:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

edit:
As per the advice of JosefZ I ran the `echo [%path:;=]&echo.[%]` command in PS, I don't how to interpret this, but this is what it gave me:

```
[C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39]
[C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts]
[C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\]
[C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\]
[]
```

To address Lee_Dailey I ran your `$env:Path -split ';'` command as well and was given an identical output, just to make sure i'm not missing something important though, here are the results:

```
C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts
C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\
C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\
```

Like I said, I don't really know how to interpret any of this, hopefully someone smarter than me can translate this to me and explain how to fix whatever I broke. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How did you _added Python to my Windows path_? Check your `path` using `echo [%path:;=]&echo.[%]` (paste the code to an open `cmd` window). Please  [edit] your question to share result in your  [mcve].

Comment: It sounds like you removed a key piece of PATH and not simply added a new record to it.

Comment: what do you see when you run `$env:Path -split ';'` in PoSh? i bet that `root` is correct and you have damaged your path list ... [*grin*]

Comment: I assume the fact that the `C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39` and `C:\Users\julie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts` filepaths show up twice means that I added them more than I needed to, but I'm not really sure where that gets me. Hopefully the edit answers your questions...

Answer (score 0):

you *replaced* your path instead of *adding to it*. [*grin*]

here is my path list. you can use it to rebuild yours ...

```
C:\Python39\Scripts\
C:\Python39\
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin
C:\Program Files\Calibre2\
C:\Program Files\Prio
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

just remember to leave off things that are not on your setup. i suspect you won't have `Prio` or `Calibre`. [*grin*]

Comment: @Taxes - you are most welcome ... and i wish you the best of good luck! [*grin*]